# Notification node isn't deleting notification and its data on ImageView click when it should be

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've got two methods in my Activity, one to add a like to a comment (clicking on `ImageView`) and notification to Firebase and also the user whose post it is gets a notification, and then another to remove it (clicking on `ImageView` again). Problem is that notification and comment both show up, and get saved to database, but then when I click again to remove the "like" the comment get removed from the database, but the notification doesn't.

Can someone help me out with the logic of this method. Something I am doing wrong because notification doesn't get removed only comment.

```
 private void likeComment(String commentId, String postId, String userId) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Liked").child(commentId).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());

        mNotificationId = reference.push().getKey();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);
        hashMap.put("commentid", commentId);
        hashMap.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.setValue(hashMap);

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap1.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap1.put("comment", "liked your comment");
        hashMap1.put("postid", postId);
        hashMap1.put("ispost", true);
        hashMap1.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userId).child(mNotificationId).setValue(hashMap1);
    }

    private void removeLike(String userId, String commentId) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments Liked").child(commentId).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String notificationId = dataSnapshot.child("notificationId").getValue(String.class);
                    if (notificationId != null) {
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userId).child(notificationId).removeValue();
                        reference.removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem my friend :)

Comment: Hey man, what's going on. Well just that... Comment is being removed when I click on the ImageView, but the notification isn't in the Notification node. Not sure how to tamper with it so that the notification also gets removed. Can you see the problem? :) In theory, it's the exact same thing that we worked on the other day, but for some reason it's not being removed. Also tried to do it without the for Loop

Comment: We solved this problem before?

Comment: Not this one... Same concept though, The other one was when you liked a post. It was a different node, and it had less child nodes. This one has an extra one, so I did it with a for Loop, but the notification isn't getting removed.

Comment: Did you try debug mode? I think for loop doesn't work.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Yeah I got rid of the for Loop. I just updated the code to show how I have it now, but still not getting rid of the notification

Comment: is dataSnapshot null? Can you look?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Yeah you're right I just checked it's null. But how can it be null? If it should have the ```mFirebaseuser.getUId()```, or no?

Comment: I think , Your comment ids are different. I check your code, it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213178/discussion-between-jmb-and-kasim-ozdemir).